# Metrics not changing when underlying data changes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I working at a company that has a ton of changes in the underlying data models, we are running on average 5 data migrations a week. We are also doing hard deletes/renaming columns/dropping columns which mean the data is changing daily. The scales of data is also a lot we have 200+ tables and counting (this is why snapshotting does not seem practical or cost effective and this company does care about cost). We also have a hard requirement that metrics can not change historically, due to above factors this has been happening often. The stack is stitch, snowflake, dbt we pull in data via log based replication.

The approach I went for was having incremental fact tables which do not take in deleted data how ever we are still getting changing data due to changing historical data.
Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do here to make sure my metrics do not change , I do not want to snapshot metrics ?

Comment: So just to be clear: you don’t want to take snapshots of your metrics, your data is changing constantly and you still want to be able to generate metrics on-the-fly that will give you the same values you calculated in the past using data that no longer exists?

Comment: Sounds like you need to make your data SCD2, and then you can query the now data, or the as it was at X data.

Comment: @NickW To be clear my hand are kind of tied:
- snapshotting is a solution but its snapshotting every table is going to rise our snowflake bill (which they don't want) and the rate the data model is changing I will be adding new snapshots every week.
- Maybe snapshotting metric is the only way but we loose the grain and detail is not something, I really want to do.
I am more looking for advice at what people would do in this situation and if there is something I have not thought of.

Answer (score 0):

If your source systems are constantly changing then this is probably good case for looking at building a Data Vault (https://www.data-vault.co.uk/what-is-data-vault/)

The suggestion to use SCDs is the obvious first option to look at when considering yiurreporting structures.

Without knowing a lot more detail about how/why your source systems are changing, how your metrics  are constructed and the impact if the changes, it is difficult to comment further - and that level of information is probably not appropriate for this forum